# How do you create a geographic map where the points are displayed as a kind of boxplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, gis, geopandas

I'm looking for leads (code, resource, how-to) to create such a map (below).

[image]

The data I have:

- A basemap
- An excel file with points in the format (identifier, x, y, min, median, max).

What I want to do is to display the points in my Excel file on the basemap as a boxplot so that for each point I have three squares superimposed vertically representing my minimum, median and maximum values respectively, each with a color code (if possible).

I tried with Geopandas but nothing works (and I don't think there is a functionality that allow to that).